# Having trouble using React Transition Group first time

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Good day! I wrote this code to test the React transition group library and eventually get stuck with the error. The script gets run and I see the data fill form on the page styled but when I click submit button form does not disappear. Error reference description: Failed prop type: The prop `timeout` is marked as required in `CSSTransition`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in CSSTransition (at app.jsx:24)
    in App (at index.js:7) However transitionAppearTimeot={1500}!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';
import './app.css';
import Form from './components/Form';
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        mounted: true,
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
};
handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState = {
        mounted: false
    }
    console.log(this.state);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <CSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="fade"
                transitionAppear={true}
                transitionAppearTimeout={1500}
                transitionEnter={false}
                transitionLeave={true}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                {this.state.mounted && <Form onSubmit=
                {this.handleSubmit} />}
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very specific. `<CSSTransition>` requires a prop `timeout` but you do not pass anything. Also your other props are not what `<CSSTransition>` expects.

I guess you are mixing up the old [react-transition-group v1](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable) with the new [react-transition-group v2](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/#CSSTransition). You are using v2 which has a totally different API.